# Guide for piezo charging?

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, battery-storage

İ am currently working on a smart shoe( Dont ask why...) and I am using a 3.7 V 300 mAh li po battery with no drop out during transmissin. But the battery life doesnt last as long as I need it to be. So I am planning to use piezoelectric generators to charge it (they produce 4V s and 2 A all together). But I am not really sure if this will work or how it is gonna work. I was thinking that it would work like a garden light, when there is no energy produced from solar panels, it will use from battery. But as I said, is this possible or efficient. If no is there a better solution?

Comment: *they produce 4V s and 2 A all together* That's 8 W, which sounds to me like **a lot** which makes me doubt it immediately. Perhaps the p-generators are just **rated** for 4V, 2A meaning that's the maximum they can deliver. I'd first test how much energy (that's Power * time) you can actually get out of them. You might also want to check if there is room to improve your design for lower power consumption.

Comment: Thanks, well the power consumption is the lowest possible, and I tested It,I can successfully charge the battery with the p electric generatods

Answer (score 1):

Some manufacturers have created solutions for what you're talking about in the form of an IC.  Linear Technology has the following energy harvesting platform that may work for your application:

http://www.linear.com/solutions/5153

It's based around the LTC3331 energy harvesting IC.  It has the option to also use a supercapacitor in addition to a LiPO battery.  This may or may not be helpful, but using a LiPO by itself may run into lifetime charge problems, as many LiPOs are only rated for 100-200 discharge cycles before they are at half their initial capacity.

The solution above uses the V25W piezo from Mide Technology Corporation, which is now an obsolete piezo model.  The datasheet for this piezo is here:

https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Mide%20Technology%20PDFs/Volture.pdf

So it looks like you'll have to find a suitable alternate piezo manufacturer, but it sounds like you've already got something in mind.

Comment: What kind of garbage lipo only hits 200 cycles before they're at half capacity?

Comment: Batteryspace has a good selection of lipos - Here's one that is at 70% capacity after 300 cycles:  http://www.batteryspace.com/li-ion-18650-rechargeable-cell-3-7v-2600mah-9-62wh-5-0a-rate-button-top-pcb-protected---oem-from-japan-korea--un-38-3-passed.aspx

Comment: One more on cycle life - https://rogershobbycenter.com/lipoguide/